# Mule Transaction scope and XA Transaction

Tags: transactions, mule

I want to insert a record into both a Database table and a JMS queue in the same transaction. Currently I am using Transaction scope to achieve this.

```
<transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
    <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(NAME, AGE) VALUES(#[payload.name],#[payload.age])]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="${queue.name}" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</transactional>
```

But I got below error:

```
org.mule.api.transaction.TransactionException: Endpoint is transactional but transaction does not support it
```

Now I used XA-Transaction

```
<jms:activemq-xa-connector name="Active_MQ_XA" specification="1.1" brokerURL="${activemq.broker.url}" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ" />

<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_XA_Configuration" host="${db.host}" port="${db.port}" user="${db.user}" password="${db.password}" database="${db.name}" useXaTransactions="true" doc:name="MySQL Configuration" />

<jbossts:transaction-manager doc:name="JBoss Transaction Manager" />

<ee:xa-transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
    <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_XA_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(NAME, AGE) VALUES(#[payload.name],#[payload.age])]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="${queue.name}" connector-ref="Active_MQ_XA" doc:name="JMS">
        <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</ee:xa-transactional>
```

this time I got another exception

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXAConnectionHandle.prepareStatement(StandardXAConnectionHandle.java:380)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.xa.ConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper.java:312)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.DefaultDbConnection.prepareStatement(DefaultDbConnection.java:250)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.autogeneratedkey.ColumnIndexAutoGeneratedKeyStrategy.prepareStatement(ColumnIndexAutoGeneratedKeyStrategy.java:36)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.statement.QueryStatementFactory.create(QueryStatementFactory.java:59)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.executor.AbstractSingleQueryExecutor.execute(AbstractSingleQueryExecutor.java:44)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.UpdateMessageProcessor.doExecuteQuery(UpdateMessageProcessor.java:59)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractSingleQueryDbMessageProcessor.executeQuery(AbstractSingleQueryDbMessageProcessor.java:42)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor.process(AbstractDbMessageProcessor.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.process(TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:49)
    at org.mule.processor.TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.process(TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:46)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecut...
```

Can anyone please solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `useXaTransactions="true"` is not working on mysql db connector. I've configured explicit `mySqlXADataSource`. It worked for me.

```
<jbossts:transaction-manager doc:name="JBoss Transaction Manager" />

<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="mySqlXADataSource" name="MySqlXADataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource">
        <spring:property name="user" value="${db.user}" />
        <spring:property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        <spring:property name="url" value="${mysql.driver.url}" />
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>

<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_XA_Configuration" dataSource-ref="mySqlXADataSource" doc:name="MySQL Configuration" />

<jms:activemq-xa-connector name="Active_MQ_XA" specification="1.1" brokerURL="${activemq.broker.url}" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ" />

<ee:xa-transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
    <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_XA_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (NAME,AGE)VALUES(#[payload.customer.name],#[payload.customer.age])]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="${queue.name}" connector-ref="Active_MQ_XA" doc:name="JMS">
        <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</ee:xa-transactional>
```

Comment: I would like to use `<jbossts:transaction-manager>` with `<db>` component for MySQL and Oracle. Its works in Mule CE 3.7? The Oracle driver to XA Transaction is `oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXADataSource`?